# In which sequence does method call work in groovy?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

I am using groovy 2.3.8

I am trying to figure out how method calls work in groovy. Specifically if we have a Java class hierarchy each having a `metaClass` like below

```
class A {
}
A.metaClass.hello = {
  "hello superclass"
}

class B extends A {
}
B.metaClass.hello = {
  "hello subclass"
}
```

If I use `new B().hello()` I get `hello subclass`. If I remove meta class of B then I get `hello superclass`.

Based on changing the above example I think groovy goes in the below sequence to find which method to call

```
method-in-subclass's-metaclass ?: subclass-metho  ?: method-in-superclass's metaclass ?: method-in-superclass
```

So how does groovy lookup which method to call?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the hierarchy is the expected object oriented programming method overloading, which is what you witnessed. What differs is the dispatching. Instead of starting with a method lookup in instance's class, it begins with the [MOP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaobject) (meta object protocol).

In layman's terms, because the MOP is programmable, so is the way methods are invoked :)

## How it works

The following diagram from Groovy's [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_metaprogramming) shows how methods are looked up.

[image: Groovy method dispatching for Groovy objects]

What's not clear in the diagram is that there's an instance metaclass as well, and it comes before the class's metaclass.

Something that may help is looking at an object's or class's `.metaClass.methods` Methods added through inheritance, traits, metaclass, etc are listed in a flat list. The inheritance hierarchy is flattened. `.metaClass.metaMethods` on the other hand seems to contain methods added via the GDK. From the list I could not tell method precedence :(

Based on observation, the rule seems to be this: the last MetaClass standing wins.

```
class A { }

class B extends A { }

A.metaClass.hello = {
  "hello superclass"
}

B.metaClass.hello = {
  "hello subclass"
}

def b = new B()

assert b.hello() ==  "hello subclass"
b.metaClass = A.metaClass
assert b.hello() ==  "hello superclass"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way and should be a comment. I have seen the diagram as I am reading the complete docs for metaprogramming. But this diagram or the docs do not have anything about class hierarchy. I have explicitly mentioned that in the question. This diagram is about a single class and MOP for a POGO not a class hierarchy. Class metaclass as well as instance metaclass although not represented in this diagram are not related to how MOP works with hierarchical classes either.

Comment: See, now you're asking a different question. The original question, summarized: Is there a meta-class hierarchy? Now you're asking about a class hierarchy (aka. inheritance). The answer to your first question is yes and it's operation is described briefly in the MOP diagram. Is there a class inheritance? Yes, the same as Java. BUT... Groovy's method dispatch includes MetaClass, Categories, Traits, and Mixins. These are not (and are not intended to be) hierarchical in the OOP single-dispatching sense. I would have put together a thorough diagram, but, honestly, you've been rather unkind.

Comment: After reading your comment I re-read the question. It is not clear. I basically wanted to know how method calls work in case there is a Java class hierarchy each having having its own meta class. But clearly the question is worded incorrectly. Forgive me for that. Please edit your answer. Don't answer the question if you don't feel like it but at least a word so I can remove the downvote. Currently my vote is locked. I'll edit the question to improve its wording.